# Array values to single array using foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with php and arrays, I have multiple arrays like following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [wallet_address] => 0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [wallet_address] => 0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [wallet_address] => 0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )
```

and so on....

And i want to make them in single array with comma like following way

```
$set = array("0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

How can i do this ?Here is my current code but not working,showing me same result(0,1,2 keys),Where i am wrong ?

```
$GetUserFollower; //contaning multiple array value
$set=array();
foreach($GetUserFollower as $arr)
{
    $set[]=$arr;
    
}

echo "<pre>";print_R($set);
```

Comment: Have you tried???:  $set[]=$arr["wallet_address"];

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA: Yes but i want all array values with comma(" , ")

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: It is either unclear what you are actually asking, or you are misunderstanding the nature of an array, arrays must have some sort of key

Answer (score 0):

The original array is an Assoc array and therefore the wallet_address needs to be addressed specifically in a loop. Or you could use the `array_column()` builtin function to achieve the same thing.

```
$GetUserFollower; //contaning multiple array value
$set=array();
foreach($GetUserFollower as $arr)
{
    $set[] = $arr['wallet_address'];
    
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($set);
```

Or

```
$new = array_column($GetUserFollower, 'wallet_address');
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [1] => 0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [2] => 0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```

Your comments are making me think you want an array without a key, which is impossible. If you do this with the example you show in your comments

```
$set = array("0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
print_r($set);
```

You will see

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [1] => 0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [2] => 0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```

Comment: @RiggFolly: i already mentioned that i want values in following way

$set = array("0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

Comment: That is the result that these 2 bits of code will produce

Comment: your code not in single array/line and without any comma ( "xxxx" )

Comment: Please run `print_r(array("0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));` and see the output!

Comment: Kindly tell me how can i get array in single line and with comma and invited comma ("xxxx","xxxxxx")

Comment: Do you mean you want to output that CODE and not create an actual array?

Comment: i dont want data like following way

Array
(
    [0] => 0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [1] => 0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [2] => 0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
)

i want data like following way

$set = array("0x127e61982701axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0xf80a41eE97e3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","0x24361F1602bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

Comment: kindly see my question carefully and give answer

Comment: All arrays MUST have a KEY of some kind.